# pass value with a dynamic id to code behind in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, code-behind

Can anyone help to solve this? I am trying to pass a textbox's value to C# code behind, by using the product id of database as the textbox id.
These code are coded under GridView of cart.aspx

```
     <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-CssClass="layoutBox" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gvHeader" DataField="prodID" HeaderText="PRODUCT" />
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="gvHeader" HeaderText="SET QUANTITY">
       <ItemTemplate>
          <div id="divQty">
                <img id='Minus-<%# Eval("prodID") %>' class="qtyIcon" src="image/template/minus.jpg" onclick="minusQty(this.id)" />
                <input id='<%# Eval("prodID") %>' name='<%# Eval("prodID") %>' type="text" value='<%# Eval("qtyOrder") %>' oninput="noDecimal(this.id);" />
                <img id='Plus-<%# Eval("prodID") %>' class="qtyIcon" src="image/template/plus.jpg" onclick="addQty(this.id)" />
         </div>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

I had perform some javascript function and I have to set the id by using (prodID) store in database so I use //input type="text".

Now I am facing a problem which is I can't access to the value of the textbox by its id. Below are the code behind--cart.aspx.cs:

I am retrieving all prodID from [Product] table because the textboxes are using them as id.

```
List<string> getProdID = new List<string>();

string sql1 = "SELECT prodID FROM [Product]";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql1, con);

con.Open();
SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
while (dr1.Read()){
     getProdID.Add(dr1[0].ToString());
}
dr1.Close();
con.Close();
```

I tried to get the value of each textbox but come out an error:
'string' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
for(int a = 0; a < getProdID.Count ; a++)
{
   int value = Request.Form[getProdID[a]].Value;
}
```

Comment: why don't you do something like `name="qty[<%# Eval("prodID") %>]"`, that way in your code behind you will get an array of quantities which you can loop through and use the kvp to match the quantity with the product id

Comment: int value = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form[getProdID[a]]);

Comment: @MMK Thanks for your help! It's work!!

Comment: @Pete Yes,it can be the second method to achieve that, thanks for your idea

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to have **runat="server"** for all controls to access it in code behind file.Please see below

```
<input id='<%# Eval("prodID") %>' name='<%# Eval("prodID") %>' type="text" value='<%# Eval("qtyOrder") %>' oninput="noDecimal(this.id);" runat="server" />
```

To access textbox in code behind, you can hook up **OnRowDataBound** event or just looping through GridView.Rows:

```
int indexOfYourTemplateColumn = 0;
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
  {
   HtmlInputText txt = (e.Row.FindControl("id") as HtmlInputText);
   string txtValue = txt.Value;
  }
}

foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows) {
 if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
   HtmlInputText txt = (row.FindControl("id") as HtmlInputText);
   string txtValue = txt.Value;
   }
 }
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Hi, I get Parse error when I am trying to add runat="server" in the HTML tag : The ID property of a control can only be set using the ID attribute in the tag and a simple value. Example: <asp:Button runat="server" id="Button1" />  However, thanks for your help.